# How to change user's data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Well, if I want to change user's email, for example, do I need to make a new controller with `protected function update(array $data)`, or I can write it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you have update function inside UserController for updating user info
and you want another function to update only the email.

Yes you can add other functions in the same controller as many as you want but all the functions should be related to each other 
For example all operations for users should be in UserController dont add operation for posts for example

```
//UserController.php

public function update(Request $request,User $user){
 //update user info
}

public function updateEmail(Request $request,User $user){
 //update user email
 $user->update(['email'=>$request->get('email')])
}
```

Comment: you r the best, around